# Search a text file for specific words using matlab and add string?

Tags: string, matlab, cell

havent been able to find how to search for specific words in a text file anywhere, so here it goes, this is what I have now and just read and prints the entire text file.
My Text file contains some words like:

**K_G_M_H_NICK_MA,0,7500**

**P_SA_SWITCH_P_MPE_VL,0,1**

If the string begins with 'K' it has to be write 'spec' in the end of the row whatever after K follows. Output has to be then

**K_G_M_H_NICK_MA,0,7500 spec**

If the string begins with 'P' it has to be write 'test' in the end of the row whatever after P follows. Output has to be then

**P_SA_SWITCH_P_MPE_VL,0,1 test**

Comment: @Chris Taylor can you please take a look in this problem? Thanks!

Comment: How large are these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB does not have this capability unfortunately.  You don't have a choice but to read in each line of text, check for what you need then save a new file.  You can use [`fgetl`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to query a line from a text file.  Subsequent calls to `fgetl` reads the next lines and remembers the last line that you read from.  You would use this in conjunction with your standard `fopen` and `fclose` to open up and close a file.  You will need a reference to an open file with `fopen` before you use `fgetl`.  Assuming that your file is called `text.txt`, simply read in the line, check the first character for your condition, then print out what you need at the end of the line should it match.  It may be wise to also trim any whitespace before and after your code, so [`strtrim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) may be useful for you. Something like this should work, also assuming that you want to write to a new file called `text_new.txt`:

```
fid = fopen('text.txt', 'r'); % Open up the file
fidw = fopen('text_new.txt', 'w'); % Open up a new file to write

tline = fgetl(fid); % Get the first line in the text file

while ischar(tline) % As long as this line contains characters (i.e. not end of the file)
    % Trim the whitespace
    tline = strtrim(tline);
    % Check if first character is K or k, then write spec at the end of the line
    if tline(1) == 'k' || tline(1) == 'K'
        fprintf(fidw, '%s spec\n', tline);
    % Check if first character is P or p, then write test at the end of the line
    elseif tline(1) == 'p' || tline(1) == 'P'
        fprintf(fidw, '%s test\n', tline);
    % Write the line as is if no conditions match
    else
        fprintf(fidw, '%s\n', tline);
    end

    % Get the next line in the file
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

% Close the files now
fclose(fid);
fclose(fidw);
```

Comment: With MATLAB's generally high FIO overhead, memory permitting it may be faster to read everything into memory and utilize something like [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) (or perhaps `string`'s [`replace` method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/replace.html)) to make the substitution(s) in one shot.

Comment: @excaza True, but I make no assumptions on the input file. It may be very large, which is why I defaulted to line by line.  Nevertheless, your comment is perfectly valid.  If the OP updates her question to talk about how big these are, I'll add this in as another method or you can add that in as a separate answer.

Comment: the file has ca 1100 lines.. both solutions  are fine for me! Thank you guys!!

Comment: @lara You're welcome. If you no longer need help, please mark either of our answers as accepted to let the community know you no longer need help.  Good luck.

Comment: @rayryeng: Yes I want to it.. I asked above a last question:  if I want to copy the line and past it in the next line with adding some text in the and how I can reach this with your code? Line 1: K_G_M_H_NICK_MA,0,7500 Line 2: K_G_M_H_NICK_MA,0,7500 spec?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want to copy the line then write the modified line underneath? What about the lines that don't match? Do you just write the line once? That's different than what you asked before but easy to do. Please confirm this is what you want.

Comment: @rayryeng: It was not different just an add. But i solved the problem. Matlab does the copy automatically in the next row so I get: K_G_M_H_NICK_MA,0,7500 Line 2: K_G_M_H_NICK_MA,0,7500 spec.

Comment: Btw to answer your question, just replicate the string before adding in the extra word. `fprintf(fidw, '%s\n%s spec\n', tline, tline);`

Answer (score 3):

If you have enough memory to load in your entire file, you can take advantage of tools like [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to operate on the entire document at once, possibly saving some time both with the comparisons and with the file input/output.

For a `regexprep` example, we can do something like the following:

```
% Load entire data file into memory (cell array)
fID =  fopen('mydata.txt', 'r');
tmpdoc = {};
ii = 1;
while ~feof(fid)
    tmpdoc{ii} = fgetl(fID);
    ii = ii + 1;
end
fclose(fID);  % Clean up

% Make the necessary replacements
% String insensitive search
tmpdoc = regexprep(tmpdoc, '(^K.*)$', '$0 spec', 'preservecase'); % Find lines (cells) that begin with K
tmpdoc = regexprep(tmpdoc, '(^P.*)$', '$0 test', 'preservecase'); % Find lines (cells) that begin with P

% Write data
fID_new = fopen('mydata_new.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fID_new, '%s\n', tmpdoc{:});
fclose(fID_new);  % Clean up
```

For a basic timing with a 2000 line file (just your two lines repeated, which represents a worst case), this approach is roughly 3 times faster than [rayryeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282873/search-a-text-file-for-specific-words-using-matlab-and-add-string/45283878#45283878), but his approach only took about 0.25 seconds so it's still plenty fast.

Comment: the file has ca 1100 lines.. thank you for your answer. A last question: if I want to copy the line and past it in the next line with adding some text in the and how I can reach this with your code? Line 1: K_G_M_H_NICK_MA,0,7500  Line 2: K_G_M_H_NICK_MA,0,7500 spec?

Comment: You can change the replacement string to `'$0\n$0 spec'`. `$0` represents the portion of the text that matches the regular expression, which in our case is the entire line.